# Stopping div/container size changing with scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, web, scroll

Hi everyone! First time posting on stackoverflow.

I was wondering if there was a way/how to stop the size of a container shifting when a scrollbar is added to it

like, if I take a div and slap `overflow-y:scroll;` into its style, it adds a nice and nifty scrollbar, but aligns all the dynamically positioning content inside of it to the left a little bit because the scrollbar changes the actual size of the content area?

I'm not great with web dev vocabulary, but I hope you understand what I mean.

I found that on iOS, adding `overflow-y:scroll;` also doesn't physically add a scroll bar and doesn't change the size of the container; all of the stuff inside of it stays centered

But if I add a scroll bar to a div with items inside of it positioned to a relative percentage, the size of the container will change and therefore all the content will move

tl;dr how do I keep my stuff in the dead center even after I add a scroll bar

I was thinking making it statically positioned but I want the horizontal height to stay relative
can I specify a static position for the x but not the y?

thanks.

Comment: Can't you make the div wider when you add the scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

you can use overflow-y:hidden;

Comment: That hides the scroll bar.  Not what the OP asked for.